# chromium puppeteer in Headless runs in different language

Tags: puppeteer, chromium, headless

```
    expect(oAttributeText.text).toBe('True');
});
```

Output we are getting as
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

```
Expected: "True"
Received: "Pravda"
```

config file
 launch: {
        dumpio: true,
        headless: true,
        devtools: true,
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--lang=es' ]}

Comment: You should add more detail to your question.